# $d(f \times g)_{x,m} = df_x \times dg_m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-topology

> (a) $d(f \times g)_{x,m} = df_x \times dg_m$?

Also,

> (b) does $d(f \times g)_{x,m}$ carry $\tilde{x} \in T_x X, \tilde{m} \in T_x M$ to the tangent space of $f$ cross the tangent space of $g$?

Furthermore,

> (c) does $df_x \times dg_m$ carry $\tilde{x} \in T_x X, \tilde{m} \in T_x M$ to the tangent space of $f$ cross the tangent space of $g$?

Thank you~

Comment: This is mistagged.  It's not pure linear algebra, as vectors do not normally possess derivatives.  Perhaps differential geometry, perhaps functional analysis.

Comment: I don't know accurately what you mean. It seems that $X,M$ are manifolds, but the target of $f,g$ is unknown.

Comment: Oh sorry @dentisDark , it was given as such. But I assigned $f: X \to Y, g: M \to N$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what formalism you are adopting, but starting from this one it can be done intuitively. I will state the construction without proof of compatibility and so.

An element of $T_x X$ is a differential from locally defined functions $C^{1}_x(X)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ induced by a locally defined curve $\gamma_x(t):(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\rightarrow X,\gamma_x(0)=x$ by $\gamma_x (f)=\frac{df(\gamma(t))}{dt}|_{t=0}$.

$T_x X\times T_m M$ is identified canonically with $T_{(x,m)}(X\times M)$ in the following way. Given $\gamma_x,\gamma_m$, then $\gamma_{(x,m)}(t)=(\gamma_x(t),\gamma_m(t))$; given $\gamma_{(x,m)}$ then $\gamma_x(t)=p_X\gamma_{x,m}(t)$ where $p_X$ is the projection, and likewise for $m$.

For a map $F:X\rightarrow Y$, the differential is defined as $dF_x(\gamma_x)(g)=\gamma_x(gF)$.

Now what you want is a commutative diagram

\begin{array}{ccc}
T_{(x,m)}(X\times M) & \cong & T_x X\times T_m M \\
\downarrow &   & \downarrow \\
T_{(y,n)}(Y\times N) & \cong & T_y Y\times T_n N \end{array}

Let's now check it. $\gamma_{(x,m)}$ is mapped to $\gamma_{(x,m)}(g(F,G))$, by definition of the tangent vector, we see it is induced by the curve $(F,G)\gamma_{(x,m)}=(Fp_X \gamma_{(x,m)},Gp_M \gamma_{(x,m)})$, which then projects to $Fp_X \gamma_{(x,m)}$ and $Gp_M \gamma_{(x,m)}$. If we factored earlier, it would first be taken to $p_X \gamma_{(x,m)}$ and $p_M \gamma_{(x,m)}$, then by $F,G$ respectively to $Fp_X \gamma_{(x,m)}$ and $Gp_M \gamma_{(x,m)}$, which is the same.

Comment: That's amazing, thank you so much Dentis!

Comment: For this question here, it this justification needed? Thanks. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434067/if-f-and-g-are-immersions-show-that-f-times-g-is

Comment: @WishingFish, this is sufficient. If $f_1:V_1\rightarrow W_1,f_2:V_2\rightarrow W_2$ are both injective, then $(f_1\times f_2):V_1\times V_2\rightarrow W_1\times W_2$ is injective, because if $(v_1,v_2) \in V_1\times V_2$ and $(f_1,f_2)(v_1,v_2)=(f_1v_1,f_2v_2)\in W_1\times W_2$, then $(f_1,f_2)(v_1,v_2)=0\Leftrightarrow f_1v_1=0=f_2v_2\Leftrightarrow v_1=0=v_2\Leftrightarrow (v_1,v_2)=0$. The same holds for surjectivity. They can also be done using direct sum decomposition and dimension arguments, which you can try to figure out youself.

Comment: Thank you @dentisDark. I guess my proof presented there is similar to yours?